# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined in three.js when loading a gLTF model and creating a mesh

Tags: three.js, mesh

When I tried to create a mesh with a simple sphere geometry and material I was experiencing and error where a property was undefined.

Example of the error:

```
three.js:16203 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined at
WebGLIndexedBufferRenderer.setIndex
```

This error doesn't appear with the model that I've loaded using gLTF until I try to add both the model and the mesh to the scene at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had two copies of three.js loaded (both the module and the regular version).

See:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/14367

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12380